# Special Chars like DOTS in Express.js route?

Tags: node.js, url-routing, special-characters, express

i got the following node.js / express.js method:

```
app.post('/pin/save/:latitude/:longitude', function(req, res) {
...
}
```

the values that get assigne to latitude and longitude include dots, e.g. 16.33245 / 46.28473. the problem is, express.js tells me that it can't GET that url. removing the dots it works... any advice how i can get express to accept the dots in the route?

thanks

Comment: So are there really 20 questions you've asked that nobody has helped you with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you gave a route defined for get in addition to the one for post? I tried this and it worked fine:

```
app.get('/test/:lat/:long', function(req, res){
  res.send("lat:" + req.params.lat + " long:" + req.params.long);
});
```

with:

```
/test/1.2/3.4
```

gave me:

```
lat:1.2 long:3.4
```